# Stop downloading after receiving particular amount of bytes?

Tags: python

Is there a way to stop downloading from a URL after a certain of bytes have been received?

In PHP there is:

```
$contents = @file_get_contents($page, FALSE, NULL, 0, 40000);
```

The fifth argument tells file_get_contents to stop downloading after 40000 bytes. I'm basically looking for something similar in Python. A search on Google and reading docs didn't yield anything. Help would be great, I'm new to Python.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the code you use for downloading in python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### urllib

If you are using `urllib.urlopen`:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> u = urllib.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')
>>> x = u.read(1000)
>>> len(x)
1000
>>> u.close()
```

`urllib.urlopen` returns  file-like object; You can specify how many bytes you want download.

### requests

```
>>> import requests 
>>> r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', stream=True) 
>>> x = next(r.iter_content(1000), '')[:1000] # iter_content() could yield more than requested; need [:1000]
>>> len(x) 
1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro in python but this seems to do the job :

```
 req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 CHUNK = 4000
 chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
```

Comment: Yes I modified my code and realized it's the same as falsetru